# Fiddler - send request for proxied client

Tags: fiddler, jscript

I have Fiddler configured as a reverse proxy so as to act as a man in the middle between a client and server. I have a custom rule that will send a request from the proxy given a certain response uri:

```
static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {
    ...
    if (oSession.uriContains("something.aspx")) {

        var request = "..."
        FiddlerObject.utilIssueRequest(request);
    }
...
}
```

Is there any way to route the request issued by utilIssueRequest back to the client machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, but it's very complicated to do it that way. Typically what you'd do is simply modify the request inside the OnBeforeRequest handler so that the URL/Host header point at the new target server.

Comment: For some reason I'm not understanding this answer. To be clear, here I am trying to 'prefetch' a page from the server - so I want to introduce a new request from the proxy, not modify an existing request. I realize that there are more things to consider with 'prefetching', but I am keeping the problem simple for now.

Comment: You then need to explain what you mean when you say "route the request issued by utilIssueRequest back to the client machine." FiddlerCore gets the response from the nested request, but it doesn't really have any way to "give" it to the client, because the client didn't ask for it to begin with.

Comment: It seems that my question is more complicated than I first thought - I have added an answer below of an approach that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize - my question ended up requiring more detail than I was aware of at the time of asking. If anyone is interested, I solved this problem using this weird method:

Topology: Windows Client --> Fiddler Proxy on Windows Client --> Fiddler Reverse Proxy on man-in-the-middle --> Windows Server

Code in Windows Client CustomRules.js:

```
static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {

    //detect prefetch response
    if (oSession.oRequest.headers.Exists("X-FiddlerPrefetch")) {
        //dump response into a variable
        oSession.utilDecodeRequest();
        prefetchResponse = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oSession.requestBodyBytes);
    }

    //detect uri that was prefetched
    if (oSession.uriContains("/some_uri")) {
        //wait for prefetch - cant find any docs for how to 'sleep' here
        // while (prefetchResponse === "") {
            // Sleep(1);
        // }

        //use cached response
        oSession.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
        oSession.utilSetResponseBody(prefetchResponse);

    }   

    //redirect traffic to man-in-the-middle
    if (oSession.HostnameIs("some_server")) {
        oSession["x-overrideHost"] = "man-in-the-middle:443";
    }
...
```

Code in man-in-the-middle CustomRules.js:

```
static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {

    //intercept response containing prefetch material
    if (oSession.uriContains("some_response")) {

        //parse response body for some prefetch info
        ...

        //compose request
        var request = "POST " + uri + " HTTP/1.1" + "\n" +
        "X-FiddlerOpt: test\n" +
        ...

        //send off to server
        FiddlerObject.utilIssueRequest(request);  
    }


    //detect the prefetch response, send to client 
    if (oSession.oRequest.headers.Exists("X-FiddlerOpt")) {

        oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
        var payload = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oSession.responseBodyBytes);;

        //compose request
        var request = "GET " + "http://windows_client:8888/ HTTP/1.1" + "\n" +
        "Content-Length: " + payload.length + "\n" +
        "X-FiddlerPrefetch: test\n" +
        "\n" +
        payload

        //send request
        FiddlerObject.utilIssueRequest(request); 
    }
...
```

As I'm sure there are simpler or better ways to do this, any feedback is welcome.

Comment: So the goal here is to have Fiddler act as a "speculatively fed" cache, where it retrieves a resource for later use? This is generally okay, but you're losing all HTTP headers (which could be very bad) and you're assuming that the response body is UTF8 (which could be very bad). Consider using the `oSession.GetResponseBodyAsString()` method. Also be sure to `return` after `utilSetResponseBody`

Comment: @EricLaw thanks for following up! I very much agree that losing the response headers is bad - I am not currently aware of a way to retain them. I need some way to encode the initial response headers into a string, and also set the request headers from that string on the client side (couldn't find anything in the docs pertaining to this, only utilDecodeResponse() and utilSetResponseBody())

Comment: HTTPResponseHeaders are an object, you simply clone them, e.g.  `var cachedHeaders: HTTPResponseHeaders = oSession.ResponseHeaders.Clone();`. I'm not sure what you mean when you say "set the request headers"-- these are RESPONSE headers, and you can set them on the object you created via `utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer()`